# Speed up workspace switching (no animations)?

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

Currently, switching workspaces (no animations, static/fixed number of 2x2 workspaces, Ubuntu 20.04.1) takes ~1sec. I'd like to speed this up, ideally by a factor of 10x. Possible? If so, how?

Comment: PS: Plenty of RAM at our disposal...

Comment: there might be a command line solution in the spirit of `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false`

Answer (score 1):

... not yet sure if this helps or not (tbd):

> (Gnome) Tweaks > Extensions > Workspace Matrix > Cache popup (faster,
> consumes more memory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the machine also helped :)